# Disable All Default Mappings in vim-go

Tags: filetype-go, plugin-vim-go

Is there a way to disable all mappings for [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go)? So I can only have the mappings that I explicitly set myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are settings for that, see [`:help go-settings`](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/doc/vim-go.txt#L1215) for a list of all settings.

In particular, the ones you're probably interested in are:

```
let g:go_def_mapping_enabled = 0
```

Maybe also:

```
let g:go_doc_keywordprg_enabled = 0
```

And perhaps also:

```
let g:go_textobj_enabled = 0
```

(Not sure if these were the mappings you had in mind... Since they're essentially overriding default Vim keybindings in a way to make them more effective when editing Go source code.)

You can also check [the Vimscript source code](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/ftplugin/go.vim#L41) to check which mappings exactly are being set (controlled by these options) in case you want to create separate mappings using different key combinations for them.

Comment: I glanced at the docs and only saw the first one... i wish there was the standard `g:go_maps_enabled` to just disable them all.

Comment: yeah @D.BenKnoble that's what I was looking for as well, I kinda wish this was standard practice with vim plugins - so you could only use the mapping that you explicitly set